# What temperature should pre cooked salmon be heated to?

Tags: food-safety, salmon

I have not been able to find any answers to this. Does anybody know?

When I originally cooked it the temperature was 145 °F (63 °C) as recommended but if I reheat to 145 °F again I have a feeling the salmon will dry out and harden but I haven't tried it as of yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If any food-- salmon or not-- has been prepared such that it is safe to eat, and it has been stored in a way that it is still safe to eat, the temperature it should be reheated to is simply 'as desired'.

In short, fully cooked salmon that has been safely refrigerated for a sufficiently short period of time so as to have not gone bad can be heated to whatever temperature you want, or even eaten cold if you really want.

Even shorter, "till it's hot" might be an appropriate answer.

Comment: as an aside, I don't reheat salmon at all- I find that it dries out on reheating, and most preparations of salmon that I make are okay cold as well.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. If it is cooked correctly to begin with and stored immediately in the fridge then is seems reasonable to assume it is still safe to eat.